# macOS Update Error - The Recovery Server Could Not Be Contacted

Tags: macos, mac, high-sierra, upgrade, error

I am not able to update my macOS from Sierra to High Sierra. It shows the error below when I try to update from iTunes. How to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally following steps worked for me,

1. From **System preference -> Date & Time**, enable *set time zone automatically using current location* option
2. Share location for the time being if asked

[image]

3. Press <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>Space</kbd> open Spotlight search, write 'Terminal' and hit <kbd>⏎ Return</kbd>. It will open Terminal window
4. Enter the following command in Terminal window

   ```
   sudo ntpdate -u time.apple.com
   ```

Comment: If you’re stuck on this message from System Recovery, you can access Terminal from the Mac’s menu. You don’t need to use sudo from here—just ‘ntpdate -u time.apple.com’

Answer (score 1):

Simple fix:   Connect the Ethernet cable directly to your laptop (use USB Ethernet adapter)  and reinstall macOS from the Internet Recovery mode.   Restart and hold <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>:<kbd>⌥ Option</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Try using <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd><kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> [Startup Key Combination](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904).

On an Intel-based Mac, this should offer the latest macOS that is compatible with your Mac and will use a different recovery server.